# Multiple getline implementation

Tags: c++

I usually use `std::getline` to read console input for online programming challenges, I've solved quite a bunch now and I've become weary of writing multiple `std::getline(std::cin, str1); std::getline(std::cin, str2); std::getline(std::cin, str3);...`

So I was writing my own multiple readlines using variadic templates and I just need a quick review if this stands correct, because it seems to me that `getlines(first)` is not returned? Would `while` still evaluate if nothing is input on `s1`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //getline
#include <type_traits> //std::is_same

template<typename F>
std::istream& getlines(F& first)
{
    return std::getline(std::cin, first);
}

template<typename F, typename...O>
std::istream& getlines(F& first, O&... others)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(first), std::string&>, "error: template getlines must be of std::string type");
    getlines(first); //how is this returned?
    return getlines(others...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1, s2, s3;
    while (getlines(s1, s2, s3))
    {
        std::cout << s1 << s2 << s3 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"how is this returned?"* - it's not, but it doesn't matter. The stream state of `std::cin` is set regardless, which is acquirable via the reference result of the subsequent line. TLDR: If the former fails, the latter does nothing and returns the reference to the already-failed-state `std::cin`. That chains, btw. I.e. this could be more efficient if `std::cin` were checked before the dive into `getlines(others...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems to me that `getlines(first)` is not returned? Would while still evaluate if nothing is input on `s1`?

The return value of getlines is `istream &` ... and it is indeed not used.  That doesn't matter much, though, because you have a reference to that stream eitherway (`std::cin`).  So even if `s1` can not be set due to EOF or some other condition, the corresponding flags are set in `std::cin` and thus once you return it (which you do at the end) it's tested in the condition of the `while` loop.

The missed opportunity here is that you can exit early when that first `getlines` already fails. E.g:

```cpp
template<typename F>
std::istream& getlines(F& first)
{
    return std::getline(std::cin, first);
}

template<typename F, typename...O>
std::istream& getlines(F& first, O&... others)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(first), std::string&>, "error: template getlines must be of std::string type");
    if (! getlines(first)) return std::cin;
    return getlines(others...);
}
```

Btw, here's what I came up with:

```cpp
template<typename... Strings>
std::istream & getlines(Strings &... strings) {
    for (auto & str : {std::ref(strings)...}) {
        if (! std::getline(std::cin, str.get())) break;
    }
    return std::cin;
}
```

Comment: Wow, now that for range based loop is _neat_!